# A convenient way to preload data in development environment datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm developing an application on Google App Engine using Maven. When I run the local server I would like to have some data preloaded in the datastore, such as the local user table. The server puts the datastore file under the WEB-INF/appengine-generated of the target directory and it is cleaned before every build. 
Is there a convenient way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:
**a.** backup and reload `local_db.bin` in your build steps
**b.** use the `datastore.backing_store` system property with:

```
dev_appserver.sh --jvm_flag= -Ddatastore.backing_store=\path\to\local_db.bin
```