# How to not to loose data in local GAE Datastore on rebuilds

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Each time I rebuild local GAE application I loose my data and then have to reinitialise empty database. This can be very time consuming, especially if there are a lot of entity types.

How can I preserve data between rebuilds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the dev server (via JVM options) to store blobstore data and datastore data in a different location and thus it will not be wiped out.

[A convenient way to preload data in development environment datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945468/a-convenient-way-to-preload-data-in-development-environment-datastore)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was simply to take a copy of the generated DB before rebuild and then to put it back afterwards.

To save you time it is located here:

```
...\out\artifacts\...\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin
```

Basically, find appengine-generated folder in your build output location and take a copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you do to rebuild your app? Unless the file holding the data is explicitly cleared by this procedure it should be preserved.  Are you perhaps using Windows and an old SDK?  In SDK 1.6.3 and 1.6.4 there was a problem where if you stop the app in the launcher it would wipe the data (well, in fact it would just never write it in the first place, but it would be preserved in memory).  This has been fixed with the 1.6.5 SDK.

Comment: Thanks Guido. I do use java version, and from time to time I need to rebuild everything for sake of my sanity. Then it clears db as well.

Comment: Maybe next time you can tag your questions with Java.

Comment: Sure. But there is always a tag you will miss. I am glad actually that I missed this one. Almost everybody here can brag that they had an answer from Jon Skeet, but I have been honoured by Guido van Rossum.  Thanks Guido. PS. Next is Donald Knuth, I guess. ;-)